# Define 2D array in scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I have to call a function defined as
`foo(Seq[Seq[Int]])` in Scala

I have defined an Int array as:

```
var myArray = Array.ofDim[Int](N,N)
```

and I am calling `foo(myArray)`

However, I am getting the error:

```
type mismatch;  found   : Array[Array[Int]]  required: Seq[Seq[Int]]
```

If I try to define the array as

```
var myArray = Seq[Seq[Int]](N,N)
```

I get this error:

```
type mismatch;  found   : Int  required: Seq[Int]
```

Why is that? I am struggling more than two hours, to find what might be the problem, but I have no idea...

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `Array` is no subclass of `Seq`, so that is why you get the error.

You can convert your `Array[Array[Int]]` to `Seq[Seq[Int]]` like that:

```
val myArray = Array.ofDim[Int](N,N) //use vals if you can, arrays are mutable
val mySeq = myArray.map(_.toSeq).toSeq //convert all inner Arrays to Seq and then the outer array to Seq
foo(mySeq)
```

Keep in mind that `Array` is mutable, while `Seq` is not.

Answer (score 1):

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_45).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val N = 10
N: Int = 10

scala> val s = Seq.fill(N, N)(0)
s: Seq[Seq[Int]] = List(List(0, ... 0))

scala>
```

OR

```
val myArray = Array.ofDim[Int](N,N)
val mySeq   = myArray.map(_.toSeq).toSeq
```

Answer (score 1):

Also method `tabulate` initialises values using a function; for instance

```
Seq.tabulate(2,2)( (_,_) => 0 )
Seq[Seq[Int]] = List(List(0, 0), List(0, 0))
```

and

```
Seq.tabulate(2,2)( _ + 2*_ )
Seq[Seq[Int]] = List(List(0, 2), List(1, 3))

Seq.tabulate(2,2)( (a,b) => (a+1)*(b+1) )
Seq[Seq[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(2, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a nested seq: `Seq[Seq[Int]]`

```
  > var s = Seq(Seq(1, 2),Seq(3, 4))
  > s(0)(1)
  > 2
```

Comment: Thanks Steven... No, I just want to define that. I do not want any values in it yet...

Comment: Ok. The first is the definition(Seq[Seq[T]])).

Comment: Thanks again. However, as I mentioned at my question I get an error if I define it like that. I also need to define that as 2D